# Yii2 restrict access by usernames

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

I use a yii2 login-logout and has a funky database with no roles. Is it possible to restrict some users on the database accessing  the website?

Can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the very easy way, you can use expression for the `allow` key like following in the controller class.

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
//                'only' => ['logout', 'signup', 'dashboard'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['dashboard', 'send-mail'],
                        'allow' => Utils::isAdmin(),
                    ],
                ]
        ];
}
```

learn more in this article: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md

Comment: No I've fixed, I don't use a access control just to restrict some usernames in my database but thanks, I can use this for future reference because it uses RBAC

Answer (score 0):

My issue is more on the fact that there is just 2 usernames I want to banned from connecting, but the rest are able to connect, in a simple code in the common/models/users, I added this code:

```
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    /*code for restriction of users */
    if($username =='admin' || $username =='lui.jin.long'){
    //do nothing.
    }else{
        return static::findOne(['USR_USERNAME' => $username, 'USR_STATUS' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    } 

}
```

On a more standard approach it is best to use a RBAC.